# What is the meaning of Kabir Luthra's expression?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, war

In [War (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(2019_film)), Basheer holds Kabir, who came to kill him and his boss, and 
finds out transmitter in Kabir's leg:

> Basheer: You came here in one piece, Indian. This was already in
>   pieces. Now I will smash you to pieces.
>
> Kabir Luthra: Found two transmitters?
>
> Basheer: Two?

*Kabir Luthra spits out transmitter and says*:

> Kabir Luthra: **One tooth is for showing, the other tooth is for biting.**

What is the meaning of Kabir Luthra's expression?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie so can't answer in context. But there is an expression in Hindi(language) "Haathi ke daat, khaane ke aurr, dikhane ke aurr" meaning Elephants teeth, different ones to eat, different ones to show. The expression in your question is derived from this https://shabdkosh.raftaar.in/Meaning-of-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%80_%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87_%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%81%E0%A4%A4_%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%87_%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87_%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0_%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%87_%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%87_%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0-in-English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd interpret this as a simple metaphor.

The first transmitter on his leg was a decoy; he knew that once they found it, they wouldn't think to look for any more transmitters, and so he was able to smuggle the *real* transmitter past them. He showed them one tooth (the fake transmitter), and while they were distracted by it, he bit them with the other tooth (the real transmitter).